# Xcode 8.1 missing 10.12.1 SDK when trying NSTouchbar

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, nstouchbar

Excited to try out the new NSTouchBar APIs. 
Went to the [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NSTouchBarCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) to get the sample code, and it crashes every time in Xcode 8.1 (build 8B62)saying I don't have the 10.12.1 SDK installed, even though I can add a deployment target of 10.12.1.

Comment: Upon consulting in the Apple Dev Forums turns out there's 2 builds for 10.12.1. There's 12B2657 (which came out today) and 16B2555 (which hit the app store a couple of days ago). I'm re-downloading Sierra to see if this fixes it.

Comment: Update: It did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are now two versions of macOS 10.12.1 (12B2657 and 16B2555).

Download the update from here (also if you already have 10.12.1 12B2657) to get 16B2555:

https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1897?locale=en_US

This will enable the TouchBar simulator in Xcode 8.1.

Comment: 10.12.1 16B2657 patch is newer than available in appstore so you need to download separate .pkg file from apple and install it. Beware! If you have NVIDIA webdrivers installed - there are no driver available for such patch and you'll have either to use slow system driver or patch webdriver by yourself, disabling SIP